# Stripe has problem: Uncaught IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: Invalid value for sessionId. You specified 'pi_1Fr...9sCWFtQr'

Tags: stripe-payments, sessionid

I was trying to use Stripe checkout. I generated session and then it showed up on the dashboard. I then tried to run directocheckout on an html file with hardcoded id. But error`Uncaught IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: Invalid value for sessionId. You specified 'pi_1FrFbeBNGS...sCWFtQr'.`

I tried to define an json object and use session.id but still doesn't work. What is wrong?

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { resolve } = require("path");
// Copy the .env.example in the root into a .env file in this folder
const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "./.env" });
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

(async () => {
    session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [{
        name: 'T-shirt',
        description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        images: ['https://example.com/t-shirt.png'],
        amount: 500,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 1,
      }],
      success_url: 'https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
      cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
    });
    console.log(session.id);
    return session;
  })().then(function(session){
      console.log(session.id)
  });
```

here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <body>
        direct to payment
    </body>
    <script>

        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XhC9cMRDNNqdkBVtHwzgYTQa00ov5gDmmN');
        id = 'pi_1FrFEYBNGSiXwN3Wx3FBbawa';
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
            // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
            // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
            sessionId: session.id
        }).then(function (result) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, display the localized error message to your customer
            // using `result.error.message`.
            if (result.error) {
            var displayError = document.getElementById("error-message");
            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

the full error

```
Uncaught IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: Invalid value for sessionId. You specified 'pi_1FrFbeBNGSiXwN3W9sCWFtQr'.
    at new t (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10765)
    at Eu (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:136437)
    at wu (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:137398)
    at Ou (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:138478)
    at Pu (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:138592)
    at e.redirectToCheckout (https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:139007)
    at file:///Users/MattMachine/sdpp_stripe/client.html:62:16
t @ (index):1
Eu @ (index):1
wu @ (index):1
Ou @ (index):1
Pu @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ client.html:62
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're passing your `id` and not the `session.id` (though I can't see where you would be getting the `session` from in your case here); you'll need to send/set/render that `session.id` produced in server.js to your html page.

Comment: I was only running server.js to generate session id and I hard coded the id in direct to check out to test it out. Do I have to send the session id right after generation?

Comment: Your html file does not contain a Session ID - that's a Payment Intent ID.  You need to include the correct ID to make this work.

Comment: Oh i see, that's an payment intent ID. How do I get Session ID, is it in the dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

"Your html file does not contain a Session ID - that's a Payment Intent ID. You need to include the correct ID to make this work" @floatingLomas

this helped me. The id on the dashboard is payment intent ID. I tried to print out the ID from the session object and put it in the directToPayment() and it worked!!!

Comment: Hi @matt, you can mark your answer as "accepted" if you feel that it answers your question.